# SPFx Application customizer not loading

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

I have an application customizer that is deployed to tenant app catalog. App is added to a site and I have verified the feature is activated but the extension never loads. I added a console log after the onInit() and it never fires. I never even see the JavaScript file called in network tab. Work fine when debugging. Has anyone else ran into this issue?

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?